# Uploading project to github. But the frontend folder is not been uploaded with the content. Folder if empty at github. only backend folder upload

Tags: git

these is the message I got in the terminal.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
modified:   frontend (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

But still I try all the recommendations from the terminal, but still folder is uploaded as empty.

Any idea? Thank you plaease

Comment: Do `git add .` to add all files.

Comment: 1. check on which root folder you had fired `git init`, 2. go to the folder that you want to commit and then do `git add .`

Comment: I try that still didn't work.

Comment: So what happened when you typed `git add .` Please never respond with "didn't work". Please be detailed.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of initialized git repository in your frontend folder, git is considering it as a submodule.
solution :

- step 1. Delete .git folder manually present in your frontend folder.
- step 2. type "git rm --cached YourFrontendFolderName" in cmd
- step 3. type "git add YourFrontendFolderName" in cmd
- step 4. type "git push " in cmd
- Note : you can also write commit message after git add and all commands are written in main folder where both frontend and backend are located.

I got same error today and this worked for me. You can upvote if worked for you.